# Count or Find number of times users had highest value based on sum of column

Tags: sql, count, mariadb, subquery, sql-order-by

Good day. I'm looking for the number of times or instances each PARTY had the highest result or share in a constituency. I am not exactly sure how to do the COUNT. My goal is to get a result set that shows the number of times or constituencies each PARTY won in a REGION

```
SELECT CANDIDATE_NAME, REGION, CONSTITUENCY, PARTY, RESULT, 
ROUND(100.0 * RESULT / SUM(RESULT) OVER (PARTITION BY CONSTITUENCY), 2) AS `SHARE`
FROM e_parlia_election
ORDER BY CONSTITUENCY, `SHARE`DESC
```

[image]

I'm using mysql Server type: MariaDB Server version: 10.4.16-MariaDB -
mariadb.org binary distribution Protocol version: 10

Answer (score 1):

You want to count how many times constituencies each party won. You can use window functions like that:

```
select party, sum(rn = 1) as cnt_consituency_won
from (
    select e.*,
        rank() over(partition by region, constituency order by result desc) as rn
    from e_parlia_election e
) e
group by party
```

In the subquery, the window function ranks each row by decreasing `result` as compared to other rows that have the same `region` and `constituency`. Then, the outer query aggregates by `party`, and counts how many times each party was ranked first.

---

**Edit**

If you want to *exclude* top ties, then you can add another level of aggregation:

```
select party, count(*) as cnt_consituency_won
from (
    select e.*, sum(rn = 1) over(partition by region, constituency) cnt_rn1
    from (
        select e.*,
            rank() over(partition by region, constituency order by result desc) as rn
        from e_parlia_election e
    ) e
) e
where cnt_rn1 = 1
group by party
```

Comment: I got the error 
Unknown column 'rn' in 'field list' when I ran it. Can you please explain what rn is?

Comment: @Enyo: my bad, I forgot to alias that column in the subquery. Fixed

Comment: great. This worked with a slight issue. When two parties have same votes in a constituency, this query counts both as winners. What could be causing that?

Comment: @Enyo: that's what `rank()` does. If you want to break the ties, what should be the logic to use?

Comment: if there's a tie, then no party in that constituency should be counted. I added a where clause.

```
select PARTY, sum(rn = 1) as CONSTITUENCIES_WON
from (
    select e.*,
        rank() over(partition by region, constituency order by result desc) as rn
    from e_parlia_election e
) t
WHERE ELEC_YEAR = 2020 AND RESULT_CONFIRMED = 1
group by party
ORDER BY CONSTITUENCIES_WON DESC
```
I have a PARTIES table which i want to JOIN this table. I tried the below just before the WHERE clause which did not work.
```
INNER JOIN parties ON e_parlia_election.PARTY=parties.shortName
```

Comment: @Enyo: I updated my answer to exclude constituencies that have top ties.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'over(partition by region, constituency) cnt_rn1
    from (
        select e...' at line 3

Comment: @Enyo: typo... Fixed.